# How to intercept all AJAX(xhr and fetch) requests via javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have xhr and fetch type of xhr requests and responses that I want to intercept.

FETCH API CALLS

I've tried

```
window.fetch =  function() {
 // Intercept the request here
}
```

and

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
// Intercept the request here
}
```

But I want to write one generic function which intercepts all the xhr requests and responses.

Answer (score 0):

By default, fetch() doesn’t provide a way to intercept requests, but it’s not hard to come up with a workaround. You can overwrite the global fetch method and define your own interceptor, like this:

```html
fetch = (originalFetch => {
  return (...arguments) => {
    const result = originalFetch.apply(this, arguments);
      return result.then(console.log('Request was sent'));
  };
})(fetch);

fetch('https://api.github.com/orgs/axios')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data) 
  });
```

`

Comment: I've written code for both the cases. I wanted to know is there any way that we can write one function which intercepts both fetch and xhr calls. And also I'm trying to figure out on how to get the request headers available in 
`XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
// Intercept the request here
// I want to read all the request headers here
}`